# Issues with template classes and inheritance - 'List' does not name a non-static data member or base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm relatively new to c++ and having a very hard time figuring out the issue with what I am doing. I hope my description isn't too confusing, but I have two separate class hierarchies going on. The base for both are class templates.

Class hierarchy one is as follows

```
template <class T>
class Order {}

// StoreOrder inherits from Order
class StoreOrder: public Order<Item *> {}
```

Class hierarchy two is as follows. The tricky part here is in OrderList

```
template <class T>
class List{}

// OrderList inherits from List
class OrderList : public List<StoreOrder *>{}

OrderList::OrderList(): List(), DatabasePath(""){}
```

When I pass a StoreOrder as the List template type I get an error in the constructor function that says

```
'List' does not name a non-static data member or base class
```

All classes work fine in every other situation that I've used them, so I believe it has to do with the fact that StoreOrder and OrderList both derive from template classes. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
OrderList::OrderList(): List(), DatabasePath(""){}
```

Use:

```
OrderList::OrderList(): List<StoreOrder *>(), DatabasePath(""){}
```

`List` is not a type. `List<StoreOrder*>` is a type.

Comment: It says I can't vote you up because I'm new here, but that worked. I appreciate the help.